# unable to get the name of checkbox through $_GET and multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

[image]

i do have the choices options as given in above image. From each option you can select one or we can restrict that you have to choose one choice from each option.

I am having problem when i select one from each option it is not inserting the value of that checkbox.

```
<input name="pc<?php echo $mitemch_id; ?>" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $mitemchch_id; ?>">

<font size="2"><?php echo $mitemch_enm; echo " KD: "; echo $mitemch_prit; ?></font>
```

In the name `PC` and this `<?php echo $mitemch_id; ?>` is the option id if option 1 then the value will be 1 and so on. how i can put the name in $_GET for the name given as above of a checkbox?

and below is how i am using to save:

```
$minsitID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mitemID']);
$insitID  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['itemID']);
$inspr    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['op']);
$iqty     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['qty']);

$ses_mem    =   session_id();

mysql_query("
insert into temp_cart (item_id, price_id, qty, ses_mem) values (
'".$insitID."','".$inspr."','".$iqty."','".$ses_mem."'
)
");
$last_id = mysql_insert_id();

mysql_query("
insert into temp_choices (temp_id,  choice_id, item_id, ses_mem) values (
'$last_id','$minsitID','$insitID','$ses_mem'
)
");
```

i have tried the below code with for loop but no use.

```
for($i=0; $i < count($minsitID); $i++) {
    mysql_query("
    insert into temp_choices (temp_id,  choice_id, item_id, ses_mem) values (
    '$last_id','$minsitID[$i]','$insitID','$ses_mem'
    )
    ");
}
```

Comment: Show me checkbox HTML Complete code.

Comment: @NanaPartykar please check the updated question i have added the code

Comment: what are you doing man?.....you are using loop for inserting data to database?......You are confused i think. If you want to save the value of four checkboxes, just use the name of checkbox.

Comment: well @ShudhanshShekhar if i tried that but with that name i can not select more than 1 checkbox like `name="pc[]"` i cant select more than one checkbox and each option should have the separate name it think.

Comment: So, *Malang Saheb*,  You need multiple value of checkbox. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying alot i got it working as below, now it is inserting from multiple names and different values for either multiple selection of check boxes or radio buttons

```
foreach($_POST as $instant => $value) {
  if (strpos($instant, 'choices') === 0) {
    $books[$instant] = $value;
mysql_query("
insert into temp_choices (temp_id, item_id, choice_id, ses_mem) values (
'".$last_id."','".$insitID."','".$books[$instant]."','".$ses_mem."'
)
");
}}
```

Comment: Glad You Succeeded. `:)`

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation. If you were helped then i was not going to put my head in all this.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<input name="pc<?php echo $mitemch_id; ?>" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $mitemchch_id; ?>">
```

To

```
<input name="pc[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $mitemchch_id; ?>">
```

**popup_item_submit_process.php**

```
$pc = $_POST['pc'];
$totalPC = sizeof($pc);
for($i=0;$i<$totalPC;$i++){
  $selectedPC = $pc[$i];

  //Now use this `$selectedPC` to enter into database table.
  // Use your query here with appropriate column name/values along with `$selectedPC`.

}
```

Comment: *..one item from each option.* Means ?

Comment: There are four options and each option has 2 choices i have to select 1 choice from each option

Comment: Then, why don't you give radio button for each option? No need to bang head for checkbox.

Comment: When you have to select only 1 option from each option. Then, better choice is radio button.

Comment: I can do it. I don't have any issue. But, right now I'm busy with my work. So, I can't help fully for correcting your code *Malang Saheb*. So, what you can do is. Replace `<input type='checkbox'..>` with `<input type='radio'..` And, try to use with that. @AhmadRazaGhausiaMalang

Comment: still same even with radio button. i need different value of each choice under any option. how it is possible i cannot figure it out